# LINQ to Entities query on related entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have 3 EF ObjectSets: Parents, Childrens and Pets, with 1-to-many associations (Parent can have mayn Children and Children can have many Pets).
For a given Parent, I need to get all the Pets that this Parent's all Children own.

I'm concerned if this query is correct or can it be made more efficient:

```
Dim query = From par In context.Parents
            From child In par.Childrens
            From pet In child.Pets
            Where par.parent_id = 1
            Select pet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is correct although its a `cross-join` - is simply the `Cartesian product` of two sets -.

You can explicitly specify a `join` based on `equality` condition.

```
var query = from par  in context.Parents
            join child  in context.Childrens on child.ParentID equals par.ID
            join pet  in context.Products on child.ID equals pet.ChildID
            Where par.parent_id = 1
            select new { par.Name, par.Id };
```

Comment: Ok, is this then a more effective way to query such a thing? I thought in LINQ explicitly defining joins would not be needed.

Comment: Your query will produce a set of records that shows all possible combinations between the two tables. It's a performance issues with large sets. Your needed results dont need that. Read more http://geekswithblogs.net/berthin/archive/2012/05/25/how-to-perform-cross-join.aspx - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/inner-join-cross-join-and-left-outer-join-with-linq-to-sql/

Comment: Thank you. Performance was my concern here and at least you put me in the right direction.